# Can I mount a Windows ISO?

Tags: mount, windows, iso

I'd like to know if what I ask can actually be done.

I have a pre-installed program as a Windows ISO. Will I be able to use it with Ubuntu 14?

I imagine it's tricky if it is possible, I'm up for a challenge though :)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's "a pre-installed program as a Windows ISO"? Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I added 'pre-installed'. Ignore that bit :)

Comment: Well, "...program as a Windows ISO" doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: Yeah.. What is a "Windows ISO"? I think he meant "a Windows program inside an ISO image"?

Comment: are you trying to sideload windows with ubuntu?

Comment: Do you mean dual boot? No I'm not. I just wanted to know how to mount and run a windows iso. Cheers

Comment: You can't "run [an] ISO" file. ISO files are just file systems that hold other files. Do you want to run a program residing inside the ISO file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I graphically mount ISOs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43469/how-can-i-graphically-mount-isos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not difficult at all. Let's say your ISO is in /home/user/files. Open a terminal and run:

`sudo mount -o loop /home/user/files/iso.iso /mnt`

Now open it with your file browser (Nautilus) with the command

`nautilus /mnt`

And we're done. Quite easy, huh? There are graphical ways of doing that, though. You can search for "Gmount-iso" in the software center.

Comment: Hi Eduardo, I followed your instructions but it just opened an empty folder.

I also tried Gmount but that gave an error.

Comment: What was the output from the terminal? Please be more specific. Did you just copy-paste or you wrote the commands one by one?

Comment: Can I paste the results and have them displayed properly?

Comment: Just paste the terminal output here so I can make a diagnosis :)